# Help me find mistake in greatest common divisor algorithm in python

Tags: algorithm, greatest-common-divisor

So I have written

```
function gcd(a, b)
  if b <> 0
    gcd (b, a % b)
  else
    return a

print gcd (12, 9)
```

so it goes:

1. gcd(12, 9)
2. 9 <> 0 means TRUE
3. gcd(9, 12 % 9 = 3)
4. 3 <> 0 means TRUE
5. gcd(3, 9 % 3 = 0)
6. 0 <> 0 means FALSE
7. return a which is 3 but it returns nothing

Could you please help me find my mistake?

Comment: I think you want to return B, not A

Comment: @Sparky - I don't think so. On the line where it returns `a`, it is guaranteed that `b` is 0.

Comment: In some languages (like Perl), the return value of a function is the value of the last evaluated expression. In other languages, you need to explicitly say `return` to return something.

Comment: btw, `<>` should be avoided; it's removed in Python 3 and has been discouraged for a long time. `!=` is the accepted syntax.

Comment: Regarding your edit: the solution I proposed worked for me in Python. Can you show your Python code?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you need this line:

```
return gcd (b, a % b)
```

instead of just:

```
gcd (b, a % b)
```

Here's my Python code showing the solution in action:

```
>>> def gcd(a,b):
...   if b != 0:
...     return gcd(b, a % b)
...   else:
...     return a
...
>>> print gcd(12,9)
3
>>>
```

This was with Python 2.4.3 on Linux.

Comment: Ah. Just realized this and was about to answer when you beat me to it.

Comment: @Templatar: Assuming *anything* about a language based on what other languages do is the quickest way to screw up ;)

Comment: @Templar - I added a transcript of my solution working in Python.

Comment: If you think it's strange when two programming languages don't behave the same way, always be ready for strangeness!